# How to undo last configure gradle in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

[image]

( details in picture)

I tried to use Kotlin along with Java project and, in the middle of syncing, I canceled it and I can't run my project now.

How can I undo that act?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: sulotion]

thx for answers
it was enough to uncomment the kotlin related items in gradle file and sync again

Answer (score 2):

Your Gradle version is `4.0` and it's not compatible with Kotlin plugin, Kotlin plugin works with Gradle `4.1` and later,
to fix your problem update your gradle.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using any version control tool like [Github](https://github.com/) you can just undo your changes.

If that's not the case and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> wont undo your changes you may want to check for local history in android studio:

<kbd>Right click</kbd>  on your project structure  - `Local history -> show history`

[image]

Although it seems like all you need to do in order to fix your problem is to update your gradel version to 4.1 and above.

Answer (score 0):

With the file selected, just click on the VCS tab then click on Local History and on Show History.

From there, a new window will open and you can compare modifications till you find the state you desire.

With the desired state selected, click with the right button on the section and select Revert.

This way you can undo the undesired modification on your `gradle` or any other file in your project.